# replace one or more occurrences of a string pattern on matching lines

Tags: regex, sed

Within an HTML document, I need to replace the '&amp' with "&" within the following using sed:

```
<a href="/cgi-bin/_fd/fetch_doc_by_uid?db=mre_hcpcscpt&amp;uid=hcpcs33140">33140</a>
<a class="coding_reference" href="/cgi-bin/_subs/efgu?c=mre_icd9cm&amp;u=icdv58&amp;p=">V58.6</a>
```

There are other occurrences of "&amp" that need to be preserved, so I only want occurrences replaced if they are within an href attribute.

Comment: And what effect do you expect replacing "&" with "&" to have? And how will it break things if you replace all occurrences? Or did you perhaps mean that you want to replace "&amp" with "&"?

Comment: that's weird, it was "&amp;" when I typed it in.  I will edit

Comment: Any reason you're doing this with `sed` specifically instead of say, `perl`?

Comment: I am modifying legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me.  You can restrict sed to the targeted pattern by using a regex before the search and replace

```
cat file | sed '/href="\(\S*\)"/s/amp;//g'
```

Comment: Actually, that only restricts it to *lines* where the first pattern appears. All the `amp;`s on this line get removed: `echo '&amp; <a href="A&amp;B"> &amp;' | sed '/href="\(\S*\)"/s/amp;//g'`. But if that's good enough for you, great.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ': again
s/\(<[hH][rR][eE][fF]="[^&"]*\&\)amp/\1/
t again' YourFile
```

change first &amp after

This assume,

ps: i'm not sur about the \& instead of simple & but i have no system to test here